# How to sort the posts by date in current week and next week

Tags: php, wordpress

So for a wordpress site I have a calendar page, where I want to display the dates of a custom post type. I want to achieve something like the following: https://jsfiddle.net/8vcyk3h5/

```
    $today = date('Ymd');

    $args = array(
        'post_type'        => 'events',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'meta_query'       => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'date',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'value'     => $today
            )
        ),
        'meta_key'         => 'datum',
        'orderby'          => 'meta_value',
        'order'            => 'ASC'
    );

    $posts_array = get_posts($args);

    if($posts_array) {

        foreach($posts_array as $post) {

            $id = $post->ID;

            $firstWeekDay = date('Ymd', strtotime('monday this week'));
            $lastWeekDay = date('Ymd', strtotime('monday next week'));

            $event = get_field('datum', $id);

            if($event > $firstWeekDay && $event < $lastWeekDay) {
                echo 'all this weeks events!';
            }

        }

    }
```

This is what I have so far. How would I go about achieving the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vcyk3h5/) example?

So I need the events happening in the current week to be in a seperate div as the events happening in the next week and the future events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be more compact but something liek this maybe? Hope to help

I didnt test for bugs, but the point is:

Make an array of events to display and then display them with a few loops.

```
$today = date('Ymd');

$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'events',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'meta_query'       => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'date',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => $today
        )
    ),
    'meta_key'         => 'datum',
    'orderby'          => 'meta_value',
    'order'            => 'ASC'
);

$posts_array = get_posts($args);

if($posts_array) {

    $lists = array();

    foreach($posts_array as $post) {

        $id = $post->ID;

        $firstWeekDay = date('Ymd', strtotime('monday this week'));
        $lastWeekDay = date('Ymd', strtotime('monday next week'));

        $event = get_field('datum', $id);

        if($event > $firstWeekDay && $event < $lastWeekDay) {
            //echo 'all this weeks events!';
            $lists['thisweek'][] = $id;
        } elseif($event > date('Ymd', strtotime('monday next week')) && $event < date('Ymd', strtotime('+1 weeks monday'))) {
            //echo 'all next weeks events!';
            $lists['nextweek'][] = $id;
        } elseif($event > date('Ymd', strtotime('+1 weeks monday'))) {
            //echo 'all future events!';
            $lists['future'][] = $id;
        }

    }
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($lists['thisweek'] as $post){
        echo "<li>".$post->TITLE."</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($lists['nextweek'] as $post){
        echo "<li>".$post->TITLE."</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($lists['future'] as $post){
        echo "<li>".$post->TITLE."</li>";
    }
    echo "<ul>";
}
```